# How To Flush a Bucket in Couchbase Sync Gateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Couchbase server has a method to remove all the stored data in a bucket called [doFlush](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/rest-api/rest-bucket-flush.html). It is invoked through the following command:

```
POST /pools/default/buckets/[bucket-name]/controller/doFlush
```

When I try to invoke this function using the Sync Gateway API, it returns the following error:

```
{'error': 'not_found', 'reason': 'unknown URL'}
```

Sync Gateway does have a way to [delete a bucket](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/sync-gateway/admin-rest-api/index.html#/database/delete__db__), but that operation only removes the bucket from the configuration file. It does not actually delete the records associated with it. Is there a way to flush Sync Gateway, or as a fallback delete the stored data?

Answer (score 1):

On the outset, understand that **Database** in Sync Gateway and **Bucket** in Couchbase Server are different.

Sync Gateway cannot flush a bucket because it is a separate entity than the Couchbase Server where bucket exists and it does not have privileges to flush or even delete a bucket. **Database** in Sync Gateway just means an object created which refers to the bucket in Couchbase Server.

doFlush does not work with Sync Gateway because it belongs to Couchbase Server API and not Sync Gateway API.

With Sync Gateway versions 1.*, since sync related metadata was stored along with the data in the main bucket or in the Shadow bucket, flushing both would have removed the sync related data. Now since sync related metadata is stored in XAttrs, flushing the bucket does not remove the XAttrs resulting in subsequent changes.